# how i can filter with foregin key

Tags: python, django, postgresql

0

I have a football stadium booking site -- the user logs in and then selects the stadium he wants to book and then selects the day and how much he wants to book the canned (an hour or two hours, etc.*) example: user John booked the stadium X on the day of 5 at 10 to 12 I want to make sure that there is no reservation at the same stadium, the same day and the same time, and if there is a reservation at the same data, he does not complete the reservation

when i try to filtter in models with Foreign key pitche filter = OpeningHours.objects.filter(made_on=self.made_on,pitche=self.pitche,period = self.period).filter(Q(from_hour__range=in_range) | Q(to_hour__range=in_range)).exists()

the error happens (relatedobjectdoesnotexist) OpeningHours has no pitche.

my models is :

```
class Pitche(models.Model):
Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
city =models.CharField(max_length=50)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
location = models.CharField(max_length=500)
name_of_supervisor = models.CharField(max_length=50)
phone_of_supervisor = models.CharField(max_length=11)
manager = models.ForeignKey(Manager,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class OpeningHours(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
pitche = models.ForeignKey(Pitche,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
made_on = models.DateField()
period = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=period)
from_hour = models.TimeField()
to_hour = models.TimeField()
timing = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=timing)


def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.pitche}-{self.from_hour} to {self.to_hour}"

def clean(self):
    if self.from_hour == self.to_hour:
        raise ValidationError("Wrong Time")
    if self.made_on <datetime.date.today():
        raise ValidationError("InVaild Date")
    #####################
    in_range = (self.from_hour, self.to_hour)
    filter = OpeningHours.objects.filter(made_on=self.made_on,period = 
    self.period).filter(Q(from_hour__range=in_range) | 
    Q(to_hour__range=in_range)).exists()
    if filter:
        raise ValidationError(f"The booked time ({self.from_hour} to 
        {self.to_hour}) is occupied.")
    return super().clean()
```

and views :

```
def pitche_page(request,id):

if request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_authenticated :
        
        pit_id = Pitche.objects.get(id =id )

        add_date = RestaurantForm(request.POST)
        if add_date.is_valid():
            info =add_date.save(commit=False)
            login_user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
            info.user = login_user
            info.pitche = pit_id
            info.save()
            messages.success(request,"Booking Successful")
        else:
            messages.error(request,"this time is booked befor") 

context ={
    'pit':get_object_or_404(Pitche,id=id),
    'form':RestaurantForm(),
}
return render(request,'pitches/pitche.html',context)
```

Comment: Please share the full traceback.

Comment: What is `period` by the way? This looks quite strange

Comment: period =[
    ('AM','AM'),
    ('PM','PM'),
] I want to know the time, evening or morning

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that at the time of cleaning, the `pitche` has not been set (yet), we can fix this with:

```
def pitche_page(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_authenticated:
        instance = OpeningHours(pitche_id=id, user=request.user)
        add_date = RestaurantForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
        if add_date.is_valid():
            add_date.save()
            messages.success(request, "Booking Successful")
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'this time is booked before')
    else:
        form = RestaurantForm()
    context = {
        'pit': get_object_or_404(Pitche, id=id),
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'pitches/pitche.html', context)
```

But the cleaning method is probably not robust. Indeed, imagine that you want to book the pitche from 3:00 PM to 4:00 PM and there is a booking from 2:00 PM to 5:00 PM, then no start and end date is within the range of 3:00 PM and 4:00 PM, but it is booked.

In order to fix this, we should ask ourselves when two ranges do *not* overall. That is if *e<sub>1</sub><b<sub>2</sub>* or *e<sub>2</sub><b<sub>1</sub>* with *b<sub>i</sub>* and *e<sub>j</sub>* the respective begin and end times, so that means the two overall if *e<sub>1</sub>≥b<sub>2</sub>∧e<sub>2</sub>≥b<sub>1</sub>*. Note that this does not take into account rollovers, so bookings that start at 11:00 PM for example and end with 1:00 AM, that makes it more complicated.

For the simple case, without rollovers we thus check this with:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.from_hour == self.to_hour:
        raise ValidationError('Wrong Time')
    if self.made_on < datetime.date.today():
        raise ValidationError('InVaild Date')
    if (
        OpeningHours.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk)
        .filter(
            made_on=self.made_on,
            period=self.period,
            pitche_id=self.pitche_id,
            to_hour__gte=self.from_hour,
            from_hour__lte=self.to_hour,
        )
        .exists()
    ):
        raise ValidationError(
            f'The booked time ({self.from_hour} to {self.to_hour}) is occupied.'
        )
    return super().clean()
```

The period is also quite bizarre: this is implied by the the value in the TimeField: if one selects `15:00`, the time is `15:00`, by using a `period` here, it means if someone books between `5:00` and `7:00` with `period='PM'`, another one can book with `17:00` and `19:00` and `period='AM'` or `period='PM'`, and this will not result in a "clash".

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

---

> **Note**: While most forms do not process media files, it is probably better to pass [**`request.FILES`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the form anyway, such that if you later add an extra media field, all views that use the form will indeed handle the files properly.

Comment: (so bookings that start at 11:00 PM for example and end with 1:00 AM, that makes it more complicated.) this problem is occur when someone booking pitche in start time 22 pm and the end time 2 am . and another user booking same pitche in same day 23 pm to 2am the Booking is happening what can i do in this situation